# Can we have same Spark Config for all jobs/applications?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to understand the Spark Config, I see that the number of executors , executor cores and executor memory is being calculated based on the cluster. Eg:
**Cluster Config:**
10 Nodes
16 cores per Node
64GB RAM per Node
**Recommned Config** is 29 executors, 18GB memory each and 5 cores each!!

However, would this config be the same of all the jobs/applications that run on the cluster ? What if more than 1 job/app is running at the same time what would happen ? Also, would this config be the same irrespective of the data that I am processing whether it be 1GB or 100GB or would the config change based on the data aswell, if so how to calculated ?

Reference for recommend config- https://spoddutur.github.io/spark-notes/distribution_of_executors_cores_and_memory_for_spark_application.html

Answer (score 0):

The default configuration in spark will apply to all the jobs, this you can set in the spark-defaults.conf.

In case of yarn: Jobs are automatically put in the queue if enough resources are not available

You can set the number of executor cores and other configuration during spark submit to override the defaults. You can also look at dynamic allocation to avoid doing this yourself, this is not guaranteed to work as efficiently as setting the configuration yourself.